# How can I reorganize fragmented flux with scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, curl, scapy

I have a problem using scapy in python. Scapy will fragment my flux and separete it in multiple packets.
I send for example 20 differents data inside one flux with only one command curl that will need to be sniff.
And when I do it I have like 4 differents packets when I should have only one.

So I try to find a way to reorganize them into one but the problem is that I need the http tag to be able to filter them. But only the first packet will have it.

How can I filter them all ?
Is there a way for scapy to give me directly one packet like it should be ?
Is there another api that I could use instead of scapy in python ?